# Electro Mechanical Relay Input to Arduino

Tags: arduino, iot

I have a 220 V electro mechanical relay (Normally open by default).
I want to read input from Arduino  when my relay goes to normally close state from normally open or vice verson.
If I have more then 10 relay I want read 10 input from Arduino board.

Is is possible if yes please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the input of relay, read it via arduino to find the state of relay. 
most probably those relay are operating @ 12volts or more. make sure to change it to arduino compatible voltage(voltage divider or simple transistor would be fine for most cases).

for your other part of question I did not understand it. Do you want to read only 10 inputs and neglect other or you want to read 10 inputs at a time?
both cases are possible.

Comment: My relay would be 220 volt , hence I dont want to step down and feed input to arduino board. I just want to input my relay state to  arduino board. Probably I need open or close circuit detection per relay is this possible ?

Comment: well, its very much less likely that you relay have input of 220v. yes, your relay can switch out electrical equipment working at 220 volt. but general input will be 12 volt, 15 volt....  I still strongly suggest that you check that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually relays have several contacts, you can connect unused contacts to arduino in 5V circuit. If your relay have no free contacts then add an intermediate relay with 2 contact groups. And use one group of contacts in your target schematic, second use for connecting to Arduino.
Generally talking there are lots of ways how to connect relay to Arduino. The choice depends of your current schematic, available equipment etc.

Comment: My 1 relay have total 5 contacts 2 for input 220 volt,  one Left , one Common, one Right,  Which contact I connect to Arduino 5V circuit?

Comment: This depends on particular relay model. In general you should connect one pair of unused contacts. Look at this example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button

Answer (score 0):

You could place a magnetic reed switch next to the relay coil and use that to determine if the relay is energized.  That would keep the voltage separated and minimize modifications to the relay circuit.